# Java lottery simulation using Sets, not generating the correct number of random results or comparing Sets correctly

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have been programming a lottery simulation, with some help from questions I've been looking at on this site. I can't seem to get the program to display the correct number of results that I am requiring, and the two sets are not comparing correctly to say how many numbers have matched.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lotto {
    private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 6;

    private static final int MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE = 1;
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE = 10;

    private Set<Integer> userNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    private Set<Integer> randomNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lotto c = new Lotto();
        c.generateRandomNumbers();
        System.out.println("Please choose " + INPUT_SIZE + " numbers from " + MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE + " to " + MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE + ", hit enter after each number.");
        c.readUserNumbers();

        if (c.doUserNumbersMatchRandomNumbers()) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a winner, better luck next time.");
            c.showRandomNumbersToUser();
        }
    }

    private void generateRandomNumbers() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < INPUT_SIZE; i++) {
            randomNumbers.add(random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE));
        }
    }

    private void showRandomNumbersToUser() {
        System.out.println("\nLotto numbers were : ");
        for (Integer randomNumber : randomNumbers) {
            System.out.println(randomNumber + "\t");
        }
    }

    private void readUserNumbers() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputSize = 1;
        while (input.hasNextInt() && inputSize < INPUT_SIZE) {
            int numberChosen = input.nextInt();
            if (numberChosen < MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE || numberChosen > MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE) {
                System.out.println("Your number must be in " + MIN_NUMBER_POSSIBLE + " - " + MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE + " range.");
            } else {
                userNumbers.add(numberChosen);
                inputSize++;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean doUserNumbersMatchRandomNumbers() {
        for (Integer userNumber : userNumbers) {
            for (Integer randomNumber : randomNumbers) {
                if (!randomNumbers.contains(userNumber)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            printMatchingNumber(userNumber);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void printMatchingNumber(int num) {
        System.out.println("Your number, " + num + ", has been drawn.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a `Set` will remove duplicates, meaning that `add` is ignored if the value is already in the `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

There 2 problems in your code:

1) In `generateRandomNumbers` you should take into account that the same random number could occur multiple times. So make sure that `randomNumbers` is really of `INPUT_SIZE` size in the end.

2) In `doUserNumbersMatchRandomNumbers` you iterate over `randomNumbers` but never use `randomNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

You store your random numbers in a (`Hash`-)`Set`, One feature of `Set` as described in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is that they do not contain duplicate values (by comparing them with their `equals()` method). Since the `Random` class may output the the same value multiple times you have less values in your `Set`.

The better approach for generating the random numbers would be to go with a `while` loop:

```
while (random.size() < INPUT_SIZE) 
{
    randomNumbers.add(random.nextInt(MAX_NUMBER_POSSIBLE));
}
```

keep in mind that this could result in an endless loop. Although it is very unlikely though. At least this loop does have varying execution times.